# How to call variables sharing the same name but ending with different numbers by assigning a variable to these numbers

Tags: php

I couldn't find a better title for this problem. I have variables like this: `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`.

In a `for` loop, I want to display these variables:

```
for ( $j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++ ) {
    echo $var$j;
}
```

Of course this won't work, but what is the syntax to do it? If `$var1` = 1, `$var2` = 2 and `$var3` = 3, I want this result: "123".

Comment: This is called variable variables http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: chances are if you're using numbers to handle a set of variables like this, you should have used an array in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braced syntax (known as [*variable variables*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)):

```
for ( $j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++ ) {
    echo ${"var$j"};
}
```

Also, as **@Alnitak** mentioned in comment:

> if you're using numbers to handle a set of variables like this, you should have used an array in the first place.

So [`array`](http://php.net/array) is definately an option, as it might be exact case for it's usage.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to solve your problem:

How to put a value inside :

```
// $content is an array of values.  
for ( $j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++ ) {
   $var_name = "var".$j;
   $$var_name = $content[$j];
}
```

And how to read them :

```
for ( $j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++ ) {
   $var_name = "var".$j;
   echo $$var_name;
}
```

But may I suggest to use arrays:

```
// $content is an array of values. 
foreach ( $content as $key=>$value) {
   echo $content[$key];
   echo $value; //same as previous line
   unset($content[$key]);//to remove a value from an array
}
```

Comment: If you like this answer please mark as solved and vote for me! thanx :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, switch to using arrays instead of these variables. If you can't, you can still use an array:

```
foreach (array($var1, $var2, $var3) as $current) {
    echo $current;
}
```

Comment: assume that 1..3 was just an example - what if it had been 1..100 ?

Comment: @Alnitak Then it is a crazy decision to use strangely named variables like these :). This is what arrays are for.

Answer (score 0):

I think one should use an Array instead of lots of unnecessary variables.
Keeping things structured, as what is held here is a Data Structure at all.
One may implode/join them using an empty value as is:

```
$values = [1,2,3];
echo join('', $values);
```

As simple as that! Think of it!

By the sake of portability, there may be the case where an Associative Array is used, let's say when the data is fetched from a Database Rowset. 
As of PHP has a way to extract array values only, one can use:

```
$values = [
    'value1' => 1,
    'value2' => 2,
    'value3' => 3
];

echo join('', array_values($values));
```

And, finally, considering the previous associative concept, it is also possible to use object properties:

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->value1 = 1;
$obj->value2 = 2;
$obj->value3 = 3;

echo join('', array_values(get_object_vars($obj)));
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
    $var1 = "1";
    $var2= "2";
    $var3 = "3";

    for ( $j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++ ) {
        echo ${"var".$j};
    }
```

and the output will be

```
123
```

The syntax is

```
${"firstPart".$lastPart};
```

which is equal to

```
$firstPartlastPart
```

You may read about it more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php